# Python return typing dynamically based on parameter

Tags: python-3.x, typing

I have a method that returns dynamic type based on the class I pass in:

```
def foo(cls):
    return cls()
```

How can I setup typing for this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this article https://blog.yuo.be/2016/05/08/python-3-5-getting-to-grips-with-type-hints/, I found solution myself:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

class A:

    def a(self):
        return 'a'


class B(A):

    def b(self):
        return 'b'


T = TypeVar('T')


def foo(a: T) -> T:
    return a()
```

This template suites my question above, but actually, my need is a little bit different that I need to work more. Below I include my problem and solution:

**Problem**: I want to use the `with` keyword like this:

```
with open_page(PageX) as page:
    page.method_x() # method x is from PageX
```

**Solution**

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

def open_page(cls: Type[T]):
    class __F__(Generic[T]):

        def __init__(self, cls: Type[T]):
            self._cls = cls

        def __enter__(self) -> T:
            return self._cls()

        def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
            pass

    return __F__(cls)
```

So, when I use with PyCharm, it's able to suggest `method_x` when I pass `PageX` into `with open_page(PageX) as page:`

Comment: Fantastic solution, this worked perfectly for my use case