# Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

Suppose I have function that takes type as argument and returns instance of that type:

```
def fun(t):
    return t(42)
```

Then I can call it and get objects of provided types:

```
fun(int)           # 42
fun(float)         # 42.0
fun(complex)       # (42+0j)
fun(str)           # "42"
fun(MyCustomType)  # something
```

<sub>That list is not exhaustive, I'd like to be able to use any type with appropriate constructor.</sub>

Then, I'd like to add type hints for that function. What should be the type hint for return value of that function?

---

I've tried [using simply `t`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=0022f87a7b5c21b73fd9c164f1159cd3), as `t` is a type:

```
def fun(t: type) -> t:
    return t(42)
```

but that doesn't work:

> main.py:1: error: Name 't' is not defined

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353024/226648) suggests [using a `TypeVar`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=dd8aa963f4468256209817f1b71d32c6):

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

def fun(t: T) -> T:
    return t(42)
```

But that doesn't seem to be right, as `T` denotes a type, so it suggests that type itself is returned, not its instance. Mypy rejects it:

> main.py:6: error: "object" not callable

---

[Using `Any`](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=a68787d63c123a944a61bef877b9a2bc) obviously work, but I feel it's too vague, it doesn't convey the intent:

```
from typing import Any

def fun(t: type) -> Any:
    return t(42)
```

Comment: Related question: [Python type hint for (any) class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325153/python-type-hint-for-any-class) ■ Side note, if you don't require `fun` to be a function and the return value is' custom class you may want to make that class generic and call it like `Fun[Union[int, float]]()`.

Comment: The error `"object" not callable` arises because you are using the _instance_ `t` as a function. Instead, you should write `return type(t)(42)`. Otherwise, the code is just fine. The syntax `-> T` means that the function returns a _value_ of type `T`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TLDR: You need a `TypeVar` for *the return type of calling* `t`:

```
def fun(t: Callable[[int], R]) -> R:
    ...
```

---

Constraining on a type is too restrictive here. The function accepts any [`Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) that takes an integer, and the return type of the function is that of the `Callable`. This can be specified using a `TypeVar` for the return type:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar


R = TypeVar('R')  # the variable return type


def fun(t: Callable[[int], R]) -> R:
    return t(42)

fun(int)                            # Revealed type is 'builtins.int*'
fun(float)                          # Revealed type is 'builtins.float*'
reveal_type(fun(lambda x: str(x)))  # Revealed type is 'builtins.str*'
```

This works for types as well, because type instantiation is a call.

If a more complex signature, e.g. with keyword arguments, is needed, use [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) (from `typing` or `typing_extensions`).

---

Note that if one explicitly wants to pass only `42` to the `Callable`, [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) (from `typing` or `typing_extensions`) can be used to specify that.

```
R = TypeVar('R')


def fun(t: Callable[[Literal[42]], R]) -> R:
    return t(42)
```

Note that any function of the type `Callable[[int], R]` also satisfies `Callable[[Literal[42]], R]`.

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for `typing.Type`, so something to the effect of:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar("T", str, complex, float, int)

def fun(t: Type[T]) -> T:
    return t(42)

fun(int)
fun(float)
fun(complex)
fun(str)
```

Note, your type variable needs to be constrained, because not all `Type` objects accept arguments, but you can constrain it to a few that do like your example.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works, but I feel that constraining `T` is too limiting. Of course, my function does not work with every type, but I feel it's not job of type hints to "enforce" it. In particular, I'd like to use this function on anything that can be constructed from `42`, including user-defined classes. I'll update question.

Answer (score 0):

You already have answer above, but I will repeat it:

```
def fun(t: type[T]) -> T:
  return t(42)
```

The `type` can be used since Python 3.10 I think. Before it was `Type`.

You probably wan something like this (to convert any value to the given type):

```
def fun(t: type[T], v) -> T:
  return t(v)
```