# Python3 type annotations for type generating function

Tags: python, python-typing

I am bit confused about type annotations in python3, specifically for a generator function that spits out generated types. I think, that specifically, my confusion stems from the documentation of [`typing.Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type). Here my code snippet:

```
from collections import UserList
UserType = TypeVar('UserType')
def TypeSequence(usertype: Type[UserType]) -> Type[Sequence[UserType]]:
    class Result(UserList):
        ... # Cut out the implementation for brevity's sake
    return Result
```

<s>The generated "TypeSequence" is doing something with type checks in order to only generate serializable data structures, not important for this question.</s> The point is that you should be able to do something like this:

```
MyIntSequence = TypeSequence(int)
MyIntSequence((1, 2, 3)) -> [1, 2, 3] with type Sequence[Int]


MyTupleSequence = TypeSequence(tuple)
MyTupleSequence(((1, 2), (3, 4))) -> [(1, 2), (3, 4)] with type Sequence[tuple]
```

**My question**: Are the type annotations I provided correct?

My doubt stems mainly from PyCharm which fails to provide for types generated by my custom generator function. Might be a problem with PyCharm but I doubt it, since the it works very well for the standard library which pretty much uses equally complex type annotations.

---

Simple example where the type inference seems to fail:

[image: Example of failing syntax highlighting]

Note how this contrasts with this list-version:

[image: Example of working syntax highlighting]

---

I also get a lot of questions of what "TypeSequence" actually does. I redacted that implementation to have a briefer to-the-point post, but here the full implementation. It does some type enforcement and type checking:

```
from collections import UserList
from typing import (Optional, Any, Sequence, Callable, Hashable, Dict, Mapping, Type, TypeVar,
)


UserType = TypeVar('UserType')
def TypeSequence(usertype: Type[UserType]) -> Type[Sequence[UserType]]:
    class Result(UserList):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            from collections import Iterable
            if len(args) == 0:
                super(Result, self).__init__()
            elif len(args) == 1:
                if not isinstance(args[0], Iterable):
                    raise ValueError("Not a iterable")
                if issubclass(usertype, tuple) and hasattr(usertype, "_fields"):
                    if any(not isinstance(x, Iterable) for x in args[0]):
                        raise ValueError("Invalid initializer for named tuple")
                    if len(args[0]) != len(usertype._fields):
                        raise ValueError(f"Not enough values to initialize {usertype}")
                    seq = (usertype(*x) for x in args[0])
                else:
                    seq = (usertype(x) for x in args[0])
                super(Result, self).__init__(seq)

    Result.__name__ = f"TypeSequence[{usertype.__name__}]"

    return Result
```

Comment: What is `UserList`? It is undefined.

Comment: Can you show an example where the type inference fails? The annotations look ok, although i don't see the point of the function. It looks like it doesn't do anything more than `list` can do.

Comment: > What is UserList? It is undefined
~~
Sorry, added the import statement.

Comment: What does `TypeSequence` actually do? It seems unrelated to the Python definition of a generator function, which is something that uses `yield` to produce a value of type `generator`.

Comment: @chepner I don't think the op means a Python generator, but is using the word generator more generically.

Comment: @PKCakeout Do you need to use `UserList`, rather than just returning a subclass of `list`? Then your return type could simply be `Type[List[UserType]]`.

Comment: @chepner Yes it is _not_ a genertor, it is a type-generating function. A function that generates types. I expected that his would get confusing.

Comment: To all others: I added most extra information. The last section likely is not very important, but since people were curious I added the full implementation.

Comment: Is there any reason why you define a *class* ``Result(UserList)``? The class doesn't have any added functionality over a plain ``list``. A factory function of the form ``Callable[[Iterable[T]], List[T]]`` would seem more appropriate than the class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202691/python-typing-declare-return-value-type-based-on-function-argument)

Comment: Note that ``Mypy`` correctly deduces the type of ``x_seq``, but rejects ``XSeq([X()])`` – ``Sequence`` doesn't take any arguments. In principle, the behaviour of further code is undefined for a type checker. Using ``List`` instead of ``Sequence`` makes your code well-typed, and using ``Callable`` instead of ``Type`` (as in the linked question) satisfies PyCharm as well. ``def TypeSequence(usertype: Callable[..., UserType]) -> Callable[[Iterable[UserType]], Sequence[UserType]]``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Use `Callable` instead of `Type` for any type to be instantiated. In specific, be explicit about the return type signature.

```
def TypeSequence(
    usertype: Type[UserType]
) -> Callable[[Iterable[UserType]], Sequence[UserType]]
    ...
```

---

A `Type[Sequence[UserType]]` cannot be instantiated, since `Sequence` is an abstract type. `mypy` flags the instantiation as invalid:

```
XSeq = TypeSequence(X)
x_seq = XSeq([X()])  # error: Too many arguments for "Sequence"
```

To be type-correct, annotate the return type as `List` or `UserList`.

```
def TypeSequence(usertype: Type[UserType]) -> Type[UserList[UserType]]:
    ...
```

On top of type-correctness, be aware that PyCharm does not generally understand complex `Type` relations. Revealing the type of the function shows that `Type[UserList[UserType]]` is simplified to `Type[UserList]`.

Using `Callable` instead allows to express the complex type instantiation. The precise signature can be defined, including `Sequence` instead of `UserList`:

```
def TypeSequence(usertype: Type[UserType]) -> Callable[[Iterable[UserType]], Sequence[UserType]]:
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry. Quite some time has passed - I could not revisit the code in question in the past weeks, but now I am back. I have no idea why your solution got -1 votes. It seems to work and make sense! The initial duplicate marker on my question might also have been correct but I cannot see that one anymore. Thanks for the detailled explanation as well, actually it makes sense that `Sequence` does not specify how it is initialized! Did not think of that, and it makes a lot of sense. Not sure if I stick with UserList at all here, so I will stick with the "Callable"-solution in this case.