# Python type hinting: function return type, given as argument, but type is Generic Alias like Union

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy, pydantic

We can specify easily return type of function, even if type we expect is provided as one of it's argument:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Union

T = TypeVar('T')


def to(t: Type[T], v) -> T:
    return t(v)


s: str = to(str, 1)
i: int = to(str, 1)  # Ok: Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead
```

But it does not work if we provide Union[str, int] as first argument (do not see at function itself, we can do something more complex with this Union, i.e. construct pydantic model based on Union provided)

```
G = Union[str, int]
g: G = to(G, 1) # Expected type 'Type[T]', got 'object' instead
```

So how to specify that return type of function should be the one provided as first argument? Even if we provide not pure type like int or str, but also Union?

UPDATE

To be more precise there is the function i'd like to decorate

```
from typing import Type, Union

from pydantic import validate_arguments, BaseModel


def py_model(t, v: dict):
    def fabric():
        def f(x):
            return x

        f.__annotations__['x'] = t
        return validate_arguments(f)

    f = fabric()
    return f(v)

class Model1(BaseModel): foo: int
class Model2(BaseModel): bar: str

print(repr(py_model(Union[Model1, Model2], {'foo':1}))) # Model1(foo=1)
print(repr(py_model(Union[Model1, Model2], {'bar':1}))) # Model2(bar='1')
```

So when I call py_model(Union[Model1, Model2], ...) I expect it will return one of Model1 or Model2 so Union[Model1, Model2]

Comment: Yes, because `G` is not a type. How do you expect `Union[str, in](1)` to work?

Comment: It's clear, G is Generic Alias , so i'd like some magic to provide Generic Alias and make function return some instance, which corresponds this alias. i.e. Union[Model1, Model2], f will construct one of model Model1 or Model2 based on value provided, so I'd like to specify that return type of function is also Union[Model1, Model2]

Comment: There is no magic. You have to write a function that actually does that with whatever logic you need.

Comment: post updated with the function

Comment: @AntonOvsyannikov  Juanpa was talking about the function to construct the Generic type, not your function that uses `to`. I have posted an answer that might answer your need.

Comment: Probably some related questions: [Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202691/python-typing-declare-return-value-type-based-on-function-argument),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a "Callable" for the `to` function, instead of the operator to construct the type?

You could then have a constructor for Union type as argument.

An example of such implementation would be:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar, Type, Union

T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V')


def to(t: Callable[[V], T], v: V) -> T:
    return t(v)

G = Union[str, int]

def build_g(v:G) -> G:
    return v if isinstance(v, int) else str(v)


s: str = to(str, 1)
i1: int = to(int, 1)
i2: int = to(str, 1)  # Ok: Expected type 'int', got 'str' instead

g1: G = to(build_g, 1) # No error raised
g2: G = to(build_g, "2") # No error raised
```

The code above only raises an error in mypy for `i2`

Comment: Works but little bit tricky actually. It's really strange, that generic aliases differs so much from Type, they should be interchangeable for using as annotations, so there should be some common protocol.