# Python: how to annotate variable, which can hold any kind of generic alias like Union, List etc?

Tags: python, generics, types, mypy

So, how to annotate variable or function arg, which can hold any kind of generic alias like Union, List etc, i.e. something that can be used for some reasonable type annotation, e.g. in pydantic model?

```
from typing import Union, Tuple, List


def f(x: 'What is there?'): ...

f(Union[int, str]) # should be ok
f(Tuple[int, str]) # should be ok
f(List[int]) # should be ok
f(1) # should be NOT ok
```

Comment: `Union` isn't really a generic alias... so something like `Union[typing._GenericAlias, typing._SpecialForm]` would work I think, although note, you are working with the non-public part of the API...

Comment: Also, I think your example should be `int` not `1` to be more illuminating though, no? Or do you mean to accept `int`?

Comment: In my particular case accepting int is ok, but it's easy to add Type to annotation. It seems that typing._GenericAlias etc is ok, but it's ignored by PyCharm, suppose cause API is not public. I was trying to import _GenericAlias from typing and got import error, with typing._GenericAlias it's ok!

Comment: Note, I think you'd need `type` not `Type`. But what is your use-case?

Comment: function which can construct pydantic model from Union or collection, see function itself in the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63661929/

Comment: Are you simply saying that `x` should be an `int`, `str` or `Tuple[int, str]`? If not, please clarify.

Comment: I'd like to pass int OR str, OR any other kind of type, as well as Tuple[int, str] OR Union[int, str] OR any kind of other _GenericAlias or _SpecialForm instances. The idea is that value can be used as type annotation and recognized by some typing tools, i.e. pydantic.