# Python Typing for a Callable Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing, python-typing

I have something like

```py
class Class1(Class2):
    def __init__(
        self,
        use_class = Class3
        ...
    ):
         do something
```

So `Class1` inherits from `Class2` and needs a parameter `use_class` which is set to `Class3` by default. `Class3` accepts `floats` and/or `strings` as input. But there can be other classes set to use instead of `Class3`. They also accept `floats` and/or `strings` as input. However, they all have to inherit from the same `Class4`. Furthermore, each of those classes that are valid inputs for `use_class` doesn't return anything. So my guess for typing would be

```py
class Class1(Class2):
    def __init__(
        self,
        use_class: Callable[[Union[float, str]], None] = Class3
        ...
    ):
         do something
```

But this doesn't incorporate the fact that the class given as `use_class` has to inherit from `Class4` in order for the code to run. Am I missing something here? I hope this question makes sense, any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of ``Class4``? Why is it relevant that ``use_class`` inherits from it? Note that currently ``use_class`` is of ``Type[Class3]`` or ``Callable[..., Callable[[Union[float, str]], None]]`` – since it gets the class ``Class3`` and not one of its instances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In `Class1` will be methods used defined in `Class4`, this is why the inheritance is important. I have seen the possibility `Type[Class3]` before but it seems this is also not very enlightening. Is there no possibility to say in the typing that `use_class`has to be a Class that inherits from a given Class or maybe that it has to be a class from a given module?

Comment: Type checkers are only concerned with subtyping of instances not their classes. So if ``Class3`` inherits from ``Class4``, then *instances* of ``Class3`` can be used in place of *instances* of ``Class4``, but *the class* ``Class3`` cannot be used in place of *the class* ``Class4``. The reason is that constructors often are different – for example, ``int`` inherits from ``object`` yet is constructed differently. Since types are "callables that return an instance", one can generally replace ``Type[X]`` with ``Callable[..., X]`` – the benefit being that Callables are covariant in the return type.

Comment: So what you are asking might boil down to the same as [Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202691/python-typing-declare-return-value-type-based-on-function-argument): Use ``use_class: Callable[..., Class4]``. But it would help to have a proper [mcve], i.e. at least a stub definition of a ``Class4``.

Answer (score 2):

We can do either of these, but not both.

To require that it be a subclass of Class4, we'd use `Type` for the standard nominal typing:

```py
IsClass4 = Type[Class4]
```

And requiring that the value itself is a callable accepting certain inputs can be handled by structural typing via the `Callable` you suggested, or simply `Protocol`:

```py
class MostlyWorks(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, value: float | str) -> Class4:
        ...
```

Ideally, we'd like to do both via an [intersection type](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213):

```py
WhatWeWant = IsClass4 & AcceptsFloatsStrings
```

They're working on a PEP, but it's going to be some time.

Two thoughts on this: Python type checkers are often quite loose or even buggy, and there's not an absolutely canonical meaning for annotations. They were designed to catch dumb mistakes in existing codebases, and to make code a bit more self-documenting.

This is why I'd advise against going too deep down the annotations rabbit hole.

Second thought: imagine the type checker is a rather dim colleague such that if you can explain it to the type checker without using advanced techniques, your code will be clear and readable.

Here you're mixing nominal typing, structural typing, and you're requiring a `Type[...]` instance. That's tricky stuff.

For instance, suppose you want `use_class` to be a subclass of `Class4` so you can call a class method on it.

What if we don't need this to be a `class`? What if it's just a Plain Old Python Object that just looks like one:

```
class FakeClass(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, value: float | str) -> Class4:
        ...

    def works_like_classmethod(self, woah: Class77) -> str:
        ...
```

This gets us back to a fairly standard pattern, and one that explicitly lays out what your code will do with this thing.