# How do I declare return type based on argument type?

Tags: python, python-typing

This question is similar to [Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60202691/1015595) but different enough that it doesn't fit into a comment.

I have the following function:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', dict, str)

def fun(t: T) -> T:
    if t == dict:
        return {"foo": "bar"}
    else:
        return "foo"
```

I'd like to be able to call it like this:

```
a_string = fun(str)
a_dict = fun(dict)
```

Pylance throws this error on the second line:

```
Expression of type "dict[str, str]" cannot be assigned to return type "T@fun"
```

And this error on the last line:

```
Expression of type "Literal['foo']" cannot be assigned to return type "T@fun"
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60202809/1015595), I should be able to do something like this:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', dict, str)

def fun(t: Type[T]) -> T:
    if t == dict:
        return t({"foo": "bar"})
    else:
        return t("foo")
```

This removes the error on the second line but causes a different error on the last line:

```
No overloads for "__init__" match the provided arguments
  Argument types: (Literal['foo'])
```

I studied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60203109/1015595) for a long time before I was finally able to make it work:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', dict, str)

def fun(t: Callable[..., T]) -> T:
    if t == dict:
        return t({"foo": "bar"})
    else:
        return t("foo")
```

The problem with this is I don't understand *why* it works. And I don't understand why the others don't.

Comment: Is `t` meant to be an object of type `dict`/`str`, or literally the type itself?  i.e. are you calling `fun({})` or `fun(dict)`?

Comment: @0x5453 good question. I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Also, what version of Python?  In 3.9 they allow using the built-in types as type hints for containers (e.g. you can use `list[int]` instead of `typing.List[int]`), so I wonder if that has any effect on what you are seeing.

Comment: @0x5453 I'm stuck on 3.8 for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem with this is I don't understand why it works

The last one works because a type *is* a callable. So the typing here says that `fun` takes something that, given something, will return a `T`, and you supply that in the form of a type.

> And I don't understand why the others don't.

The first version doesn't work because there is no binding between the left and right side of `->`. So you can pass a typevar, but you cannot specify that the specific on the left must be the specific on the right. To put it differently, if the argument is a `dict`, then according to the signature, the return type doesn't have to be a dict, but rather still the types specified by the typevar (it is a bit confusing, because the same symbol - `T` - appears in both. However, `T` means here "one of ...").

The second version doesn't work because the `return` is indicating that you're returning a type as well, as far as the typechecker is concerned.

Comment: Regarding the first version, I'm not sure what you mean by bindings. As for the second, do you mean `if t == dict: return t({"foo": "bar"})` returns an instance of the `Type` class?

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge Updated the answer to explain further.

Comment: Effectively, `Type[T]` has to work for *any* type `T`, but not all types have the same signature when called. `mypy` is looking at the first use of `t` in the body and assuming that's what *all* uses of `t` must look like. `Callable[..., T]` weakens the restriction by accepting any callable, regardless of what type its arguments need to be. It's not so much that it knows that `dict` takes one kind of argument but `str` another, as `mypy` simply not *caring* what the argument type is anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `typing.overload` here.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, overload, Callable


T = TypeVar('T')


@overload
def fun(t: Type[dict]) -> dict:
    ...


@overload
def fun(t: Type[str]) -> str:
    ...


def fun(t: Callable[..., T]) -> T
    if t == dict:
        return t({"foo": "bar"})
    else:
        return t("foo")
```

This should allow `fun(dict)` and `fun(str)`, but no calls with a different type, while also ensuring that `fun` does, indeed, return a value of the type passed as an argument.

Comment: @AmiTavory you think? The overloads are simple enough but you're still left with `fun(t: Callable[..., T]) -> T` which is the confusing part to me. Anyways this doesn't really answer my question but is a fine alternative.