# How to specify a return type as parameter in python?

Tags: python, types

I'm looking for a way to pass on a type as parameter to a function which will then get a value from  somewhere (in this case from a configuration file), check that type is correct and then return the value. The function should have an appropriate return type specification to check that.

Basically, I want something like this:

```py
def get_from_cfg(key: str, t: type) -> t:
    # get value from somewhere
    val = 123
    # ...
    if not isinstance(val, t):
        raise TypeError('Invalid type')
    return val

get_from_cfg('some_key', int)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work.

One option I found would be to use a `TypeVar` parameter like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def get_from_cfg(key: str, t: T) -> T:
    # get value from somewhere
    val = 123
    # ...
    if not isinstance(val, type(t)):
        raise TypeError('Invalid type')
    return val


get_from_cfg('some_key', 0)
```

But that is a bit weird since instead of specifying the type to check for, you need to pass in a random value of that type.

There has to be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

EDIT: To clarify, ideally, this should not only work with simple typed. For example, it would be great if union types would work as well:

```py
get_from_cfg('some_key', int|None)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Typing: declare return value type based on function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202691/python-typing-declare-return-value-type-based-on-function-argument)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've somehow missed that question. Unfortunately, that the answers to that question also wouldn't work for types like `int | None` which isn't a problem for that question, but in my case, it would be nice to deal with that.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using `Type` from the `typing` module.

An example:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def get_from_cfg(key: str, t: Type[T]) -> T:
    # get value from somewhere
    val = 123
    # ...
    if not isinstance(val, t):
        raise TypeError('Invalid type')
    return val

result = get_from_cfg('some_key', int)
```

This should allow you to directly specify the type without needing to pass an instance of that type.
Basically, the `Type[T]` is a special construct indicating that `t` should be a type, and `T` is the type variable representing that type. This way, you can call the function `get_from_cfg` with the desired type as an argument directly.

Comment: `Type` was deprecated in Python 3.9; use `type` instead :`def get_from_cfg(key: str, t: type[T]) -> T:`.

Comment: Great, thanks! That's already a big step in the right direction. It seems to work well with simple types. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with union types, though. For example, `get_from_cfg('some_key', int|None)` will result in `pyright` complaining about incompatible types:

Argument of type "type[int] | type[None]" cannot be assigned to parameter "t" of type "type[T@get_from_cfg]" in function "get_from_cfg"

Comment: @LarsKiesow You should be able to use Union from the same module in this case. For example, you could import it from typing module and specify signature like:
`def get_from_cfg(key: str, t: Type[Union[int, None]]) -> Union[int, None]:`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you plan on *producing* the value of `val`, it may be better to be explicit and pass a parser/converter directly. If it generates the return value, you can declare its return type to be the return type of the function that uses it.

```
def get_from_cfg(key: str, t: Callable[[str], T]) -> T:
    v = some_mapping[key]
    return t(v)
```

Comment: That would actually work. Thank you. Unfortunately, it is pretty inconvenient. For some type like `int`, this is okay since I can just use the built-in `int` like `get_from_cfg('key', int), but for complex types, you would need a separate validation function for every type. Still, this might be the way I do it if I don't find anything better :-)

Comment: That's why I asked (somewhat obliquely) how you are producing the value. The code that produces it would be a good candidate for the argument (think inversion of control, dependency injection, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function here. Add More types if required. Modify this according to your requirement. The function takes two arguments. The first one being a value, And the second argument is the type. The second argument should be given as string(within quotes) and this can be one of the short forms of the required type. For instance, if you want to check whether the value is float, the second argument can be one of these :'flt' or 'float' or 'ft' or 'fl'.
So this function will check whether the given value is of given type. If true returns the value and type else returns 'Value Error'.

```
def get_from_cfg(val, t):
    st = 'str', 'st', 'sr'
    num = 'int', 'in', 'it'
    dec = 'flt', 'float', 'ft', 'fl'
   
    cond1, cond2, cond3 = isinstance(val, str), isinstance(val, int), isinstance(val, float)
    if t in st:
        con = cond1
        key = 'str'
    elif t in num :
        con = cond2
        key = 'int'
    else:
        con = cond3
        key = 'float'  
return (val, key) if con else 'Value Error'
    


r = get_from_cfg(15.05, 'ft')
print(r) #output : (15.05, 'float')

r = get_from_cfg('abc', 'ft')
print(r) #output : Value Error

r = get_from_cfg('abc', 'st')
print(r) #output : ('abc', 'str')

r = get_from_cfg(15, 'st')
print(r) #output : Value Error

r = get_from_cfg(15, 'in')
print(r) #output : (15, 'int')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is more or less a more hard-coded and complex version of my example, leaving out any type hints. The type check in my function already works if I pass in a type as parameter. My problem are the type hints. Especially for the return type. So unfortunately, this doesn't really help.